# SSRS on Non-SQL Azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I noticed that Azure Reporting is being discontinued. The alternative is to set up SSRS on a VM. In the Azure world, can SSRS be installed and configured on a server that is not running SQL server and connect it's two required database to Azure Databases? Or do the databases SSRS needs have to be full SQL Server databases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VMs in the Azure gallery contain a full installation of SQL Server - meaning all services like SQL Server, Analysis Services, Integration Services, etc. The SQL Server license cost is included in the hourly rate your pay for the server. Obviously, you can choose to create two VMs of this sort and use the SSRS on one server and the Database Engine on another. On the SSRS server, you could disable or uninstall the Database Engine if you want. This is a more expensive option, but it will work.

Alternatively, you could build your own VM using Hyper-V, and just install the SSRS components you want to use. [You can prep the VM as an Azure image and upload it into Azure.](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/common-tasks/upload-a-vhd/) Of course, you will have to supply your own license for SQL Server.

I do not believe that the Reporting Services databases can be created/stored using the SQL Database service provided in Azure. You need to use the full SQL Server installation.